# FPDF & While loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, while-loop, fpdf

I am currently working on an invoice script which currently pulls the information from MySql and then converts that information into a PDF and emails it using PHPmailer.

The part im stuck with is how I would convert this into a PDF. I would like to be able to post the orderid to a following page which then does the conversion to PDF.

I have attached my script below for some help.

```
  <?php 
session_start();
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $con = mysqli_connect('***', '***', '***', '***');
    if (!isset($con)) {
        die("Connection to Aurora System failed.");
    }

    $orderid = $_POST['order_id'];
    ?>


<!doctype html>
<html>
<body class="body page-orderview clearfix">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <p class="text text-1">SMKD Field Force</p>
<a href="front.php"><img class="image" src="images/smkd_logo.png"></a>
  <p class="text text-2">Welcome</p>
  <p class="text text-3">Order <?php echo "$orderid"; ?>


    <table>
      <tr>
    <th>Product Title</th>
    <th>Nicotine Strength</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price (inc. VAT)</th>
  </tr>
    <?php 

    $query = "SELECT `product`, `variant`, `quantity` FROM orders_detail WHERE order_id = '$orderid'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $quantitytotal = 0;
    $quantityline = - 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $product = $row['product'];
        $stuff = $row['quantity'];
        $variant = $row['variant'];
        $linequantity = $stuff;
        $quantitytotal += $stuff;

        $pricequery = "SELECT product_price FROM products WHERE product_name = '$product'";
        $priceresult = mysqli_query($con, $pricequery);
        $pricetag = 0;
        $priceline = 0;
        while ($rowprice = mysqli_fetch_assoc($priceresult)) {
            $price = $rowprice['product_price'];
            $pricetag += $price;
            $priceline = $price;
        }
        $linetotal = $priceline * $linequantity;
        echo  '<tr><td>' . $product .' </td> ' . '<td>' . $variant . '</td>' . ' <td> ' . $linequantity . '</td>' . '<td> £' . $linetotal . '</td> </tr>';  

    }
    $total = $pricetag * $quantitytotal;
        ?> 



    <tr><td>Total Ex Vat:</td><td> Total Inc Vat:</td></tr>

    <tr><td><?php echo "£" . ($total / 1.2);?></td>
    <td><?php   echo "£" . $total; ?></td></tr>
</table>
</p><br>
<form method="post" action"pdfinvoice.php">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $orderid; ?>" name="orderid">
</form>
Submit button goes here
</body>
</html>
```

I wouuld not object to converting the entire page to a PDF but from what I understand this isn't possible with FPDF.

Regards & Many thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't make it too complex in regard to styling and html elements, I suggest taking a look at https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf, it's a pretty powerfull HTML to PDF converter library and is supports quite a lot of HTML.

Just forms and the like aren't going to work inside of the pdf, so don't include those (they may or may not be rendered, depends on the exact html tag.)

Answer (score 0):

I actually just completed the same task a couple weeks ago. My page doesn't display the pdf however. Upon completion of checkout the page displays a success message and emails the pdf to the user.

Once you download and include the the FPDF library in your php file. Its just a matter of creating the FPDF object, adding to it, and outputting it.

```
    require "Resources/PDF/fpdf.php";

    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 0);
    $pdf->SetLeftMargin(8);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',20);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(255);
    $pdf->SetFillColor(0,153,204);
    $pdf->Cell(194,10,'MyCompany Inc.','LRT',0,'L', true);
    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','I',12);
    $pdf->Cell(97,10,'Invoice #: '.$id.''.$cnt.'','LB',0,'L', true);
    $pdf->Cell(97,10, "Date: ".date("d-m-Y")."  ",'RB',0,'R', true);
    $pdf->Ln();
    $pdf->SetTextColor(0,153,204);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Ship to:',0,4);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','I',12);
    $pdf->Cell(40,5, $_POST['shippingName'],0,5);
    $pdf->Cell(40,5, $COMP,0,6);
    $pdf->Cell(40,5, $EMAIL,0,6);
    $pdf->Cell(40,5, $_POST['shippingPhoneNumber'],0,7);
    $pdf->Cell(40,5, $_POST['shippingAddress'],0,8);
    $pdf->Cell(40,5, $_POST['shippingPostalCode'],0,9);
    $pdf->Cell(40,5, $_POST['shippingCity'],0,10);
    $pdf->Cell(40,5, $_POST['shippingProvince'],0,11);
    $pdf->Cell(40,5, $_POST['shippingCountry'],0,12);
    $pdf->Output(); //should display the pdf to the page
```

Output("filepath"); can save pdf to directory where you could then email the file. 
The above will create a header and list User's info passed in through $_POST variables.

The FPDF documentation can be helpful at times. http://www.fpdf.org/